# Finding OPE from conformal Ward identity WZW model

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ward-identity, wess-zumino-witten

I'm working through section 15.1.3. of Di Francesco's CFT textbook. I don't understand the steps going between (15.42) and (15.43). They say to substitute
$\delta_\omega J = \sum_{b,c} i f_{abc} \omega^b J^c - k \partial_z \omega^a$ into the Ward identity
\begin{equation} 
    \delta_{\omega, \bar{\omega}}\left\langle X \right\rangle = -\frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint dz \sum_a \omega^a \left\langle J^a X \right\rangle + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \sum_a \bar{\omega}^a \left\langle \bar{J}^a X \right\rangle
\end{equation}
to get the OPE
\begin{equation} 
J^a(z) J^b (w) \sim \frac{k \delta_{ab}}{(z-w^2)} + \sum_c i f_{abc} \frac{J^c(w)}{(z-w)}. 
\end{equation}
I know I need to use the residue theorem but I can't see the steps I need to take to get to the OPE. Thanks very much for any help you can give me.

Comment: Please explain which step you find harder than the analogous proof of the $T(z)T(w)$ OPE.